# Prestashop 1.7 debug bar

Tags: prestashop, symfony-2.8, prestashop-1.7, phpdebugbar

How to have the debug bar on all the website ?
In the administration side I activate the `debug mode`, but the Symfony debug-bar  is visible only in the "modules" part.
Is it possible to display it on all the website like the transport section?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't possible. Debug bar is available only on that pages which are built on symfony(Product and Modules pages so far, and Modules Catalog, Performance, System Information if you use Prestashop 1.7.3.0 version).

Answer (score -1):

i don't own this company (and i didn't read up on it that well) but would [this](https://www.presta-debug.com/) be the thing you are looking for?